# During Purim Meshulash, why does the Seudah take place on Sunday?

Tags: calendar, purim, shushan-purim, yerushalayim-jerusalem

When Shushan Purim falls on Shabbat, residents of Jerusalem spread the observances of Purim over three days: Megillah reading <strike>& meshloach manot</strike>  on Friday, Al HaNissim and Purim Torah reading on Shabbat, and the Seudah (meal) and mishloach manot on Sunday.

Why would the Seudah be postponed to a day which is not actually Purim *anywhere*, when one can no longer include Al HaNissim in birkat ha-mazon? On Shabbat I suppose there wouldn't be much to distinguish it from one's regular Shabbat meal? Wouldn't it make more sense to have the Seudah early-ish on Friday?

Comment: "מקור הדין המחייב את דחיית הסעודה ליום ראשון הוא בתלמוד הירושלמי. כיוון שלא קיימת התייחסות לנושא בתלמוד הבבלי רוב פוסקי ההלכה קיבלו את דעת התלמוד הירושלמי בנושא ופסקו שיש לעשות את הסעודה ומשלוח מנות ביום ראשון" "The source for this is in the Jerusalem Talmud. Since the Babylonian Talmud doesn't discuss this, most *poskim* accepted the opinion of the Jerusalem Talmud, and have ruled that the meal (of the פורים משולש) and mishloach manos be done on Sunday." ~[Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D#.D7.A4.D7.95.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.9D_.D7.9E.D7.A9.D7.95.D7.9C.D7.A9)

Comment: Wikipedia also mentions some dissenting opinions, at that link. I ran out of room in my last comment :) ... see also some discussion of this question [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=3328) and [here](http://therelevantparsha.blogspot.com/2008/03/purim-afterthoughts-part-ii.html)

Comment: See Yerushalmi Megilla 1:4

Comment: Mishloach Manos is done on Sunday in such a case http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/1301

Comment: Alright, I was mistaken about the mishloach manot. Not really pertinent to the question I posed though.

Comment: According to my answer it is most pertinent, as that is the reason the Seuda takes place on Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard in the name of the Meiri that since the Mitzva of Mishloach Manos is delayed until Sunday, and one of the purposes of Mishloach Manos is that the poor should have what to eat, therefore the Seuda is also delayed until Sunday in order the poor should get what to eat.

Comment: Ok, so why are Mishloach Manos pushed off?

Comment: @DoubleAA: You can not carry on Shabbos

Comment: וכ"כ המאירי [מגילה ה' א']: "סעודת פורים התבאר שם גם כן שמאחרין ולא מקדימין שאע"פ שהקדימו קריאת המגילה אין שמחה בדין קדימה ונח לנו שתתאחר, ונראה הטעם שהרי נאמר בפירוש לעשות אותם ימי משתה ושמחה אותם ולא אחרים במקומם נמצא שלא חלה זמן חובתה עדיין ומאחר שלא חל זמן חובתה עדיין מאחרין אותה, מוטב שתדחה לזמן שהגיע חיובה משתעשה לזמן שלא הגיע חיובה עדיין. ובתלמוד המערב שאלו ויעשה אותה, והשיבו לעשות אותם כתיב את ששמחתו תלויה בב"ד יצא זה ששמחתו תלויה בידי שמים, ועוד שהרי משלוח מנות היה נדחה.

Comment: @DoubleAA In order: 1) the ***kinyan*** isn't the mitzvah - the ***shelichus*** is. 2) You aren't sharing food, you are sending it to someone else - generally someone who's seudah you will not be attending, and preferably by a third party. 3) Three reasons: either A) Lo Plug between food, books, etc. or B) the gezeirah of kinyan came before the institution of Purim, so Chazal of that time ***couldn't*** craft an exception to a standing rule or C) MM often includes non food items (trays, etc.) that are being koneh at the same time and AREN'T part of the mitzvah.